# Struggling with CORS error using Spring,Angularjs and Ionic frame work

Tags: angularjs, spring, ionic-framework, annotations

**Controller.java**

In Controller class,I have defined url and while accessing from browser its working fine.
But when accessing the same url request from Ionic program, getting CORS error.Due to this error i have added necessary content in doFilter method too.But still left helpless.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/service")
public class Controller implements Filter {

@RequestMapping(value = "/name", method = RequestMethod.POST,
        headers = "content-type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded",produces="application/json")
public String reg(@ModelAttribute Farmer farmer) {

    System.out.println("Getting request from Mobile client...!!" + farmer);//farmer.firstName is null
    String result = "Hello..!";
    System.out.println("Request processed");
    return result;
}
@Override
public void destroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) resp;
    System.out.println("External request start..!!");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT,GET,DELETE");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with");

    chain.doFilter(req, resp);
    System.out.println("External request end..!!");
}

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

**Farmer.java**

```
public class Farmer {
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
//getters and setters
}
```

I have edited my question.Please do check it.
Thank you.

Comment: what is the log of the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going with lot of trials and referring examples.Finally fixed this issue.So just thought of adding here.If in case anyone might need it.

> This fixes just by adding
>   @CrossOrigin,@RestController,consumes="application/json" in your
>   controller method.

```
@CrossOrigin
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/service")
public class Controller implements Filter {
@RequestMapping(value = "/name", method = RequestMethod.POST,
    headers = "content-type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded",consumes="application/json")
```

public String reg(@ModelAttribute Farmer farmer) {

```
System.out.println("Getting request from Mobile client...!!" + farmer);//farmer.firstName is null
String result = "Hello..!";
System.out.println("Request processed");
return result;
}
@Override
public void destroy() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp, FilterChain chain)
    throws IOException, ServletException {
HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) resp;
System.out.println("External request start..!!");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT,GET,DELETE");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with");

chain.doFilter(req, resp);
System.out.println("External request end..!!");
}

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you use chrome you must start it with the flag `--disable-web-security` or install the extension [Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: *](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi).

It's not a code problem, when you build your app with cordova or phonegap build the error message will not be throw.

Comment: Here's a related response http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome

Comment: i have already added that extension before.But still messed up with Allow-Control-Allow-Origin issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it, add this to a class annotated with `component` or `configuration`:

```
 @Bean
        public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
            return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                    registry.addMapping("/service/**").allowedOrigins("*").allowedMethods("GET", "POST","PUT", "DELETE");


                }
            };
        }
```